# Is there a way to regenerate PO files from weblate with new formatting?

Tags: python, django, translation, weblate

In an attempt to reduce the frequency of merge conflicts and unhelpfully large diffs in weblate generated PO files I have opted to use the "no wrap" formatting option of the "Customize gettext output" addon on an existing project.

This seems to work fine however the nowrap formatting is only applied to strings that are modified. Is there a way I force weblate to regenerate all strings in the PO files even if the string is unchanged (thereby applying nowrap to every translation string in the project/component)?

https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/addons.html#customize-gettext-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to achieve this in Weblate. What you can however easily do is to add `--no-wrap` parameter to `msgmerge` (assuming you use this for updating the po files).